# Xcode Incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning void from a function with result type NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

Why do I get this warning in Xcode?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried deleting your Derived Data, cleaning your project with Command-Shift-k and Command-Shift-Option-k, and then restarting xcode? I've found that strange warnings such as this can be removed with this procedure.

Comment: Thank you. I tried what you said before I posted this question, but in vain. Some time later I repeat the procedure several times.. Mysteriously, the warning goes away..

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like an xcode bug to me.

Comment: And thanks for two shortcuts. It helps:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode expects return statement at the end of the function

it is better to do something like this:

NSInteger *myInt = nil;

```
 //your if statement where you changing "myInt" instead of returning
```

return myInt